# More than 14 API search results for Twitter Sentiment Analysis?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, sentiment-analysis, twitterapi-python

I am currently using Tweepy to access the Twitter API for some sentiment analysis.
**However, when I run the following code:**

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True)


public_tweets = api.search('Donald Trump')
```

I only get **14 tweets**? Is There any way to retrieve more/specify that you want more??
Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Those might really be the only tweets that match your phrase. Have you tried changing the phrase?

Comment: @TechniCollins Yeah... I've tried making it more general with just the phrases "Trump" or "Donald". I just don't see any way (with the election coming up), how I'm only getting 14 results for each of those 3 searches. Maybe Twitter API poses certain limits to novices? No idea. I'll keep trying different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True)

your_query = "your query"
public_tweets = api.search(your_query, count=100)
```

This is the maximum number of tweets you can get in one request. By default the count is set to 15. Moreover by default it shows the most recent 100 tweets which include your query.

If you need more than 100 Tweets you need either save the minimum id and set is as max_id attribute or use tweepy.cursor. If you search you will find its tutorial on tweepy doc.